# Facebook/Unity SDK, Web build login not working

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have tried changing the InteractiveConsole script that comes with the Facebook/Unity SDK to simply make it use Login via the facebook account, as a start. Before building for the web it works fine (inside Unity), I get the access token window and I can see my own facebook ID in the console afterwards. But when I build it for the web and click on the same login button nothing happens. I have no idea why.
Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public sealed class InteractiveConsole : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region FB.Init() example

    private void CallFBInit()
    {
    FB.Init(OnInitComplete, OnHideUnity);
    }

    private void OnInitComplete()
    {
        Debug.Log("FB.Init completed: Is user logged in? " + FB.IsLoggedIn);
        CallFBLogin ();
    }

    private void OnHideUnity(bool isGameShown)
    {
        Debug.Log("Is game showing? " + isGameShown);
    }

    #endregion

    #region FB.Login() example

    private void CallFBLogin()
    {
        FB.Login("email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
    }

    void LoginCallback(FBResult result)
    {
        if (!FB.IsLoggedIn)
        {
            Debug.Log ("User cancelled login.");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log ("User ID: " + FB.UserId);
            if(FB.IsLoggedIn)
                Application.LoadLevel("main");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (Button("Login"))
        {
            CallFBInit();
        }
    }
    private bool Button(string label)
    {
        return GUILayout.Button(
            label
            );
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

There's more I'd like to understand, is the Access Token Unity window there to replace the usual Login/Asking for Permissions window in the final game (as seen in basically every app used on facebook)? If not, how do I get the proper Login window?

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem, however I did find a way to make it work. If you directly link to the Unity Binary URL instead of linking to a secure Canvas page you should be able to login. However I don't know how to change the looks of the page around the unity3D application.

Comment: That's what I already did. Actually, now that I've tried it on facebook it's working. I didn't know there were that much differences between trying inside Unity, trying the build on my PC and trying it using facebook canvas. The Login button still does nothing in the local web build, but it works fine now that I've put it on facebook. I'm not getting the page surrounding the game though, I'm just getting the scenes I set up in Unity.